# SQL SELECT rows from one table using an array taken from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I need to do something like this:

```
$user_id = (int) get_logged_in_userud();

**$thread_ids** = $wpdb->query( "SELECT thread_id FROM $tableName1 WHERE user_id = %s), $user_id);

$iterateRows = $wpdb->query( "SELECT thread_id FROM $tableName2 WHERE thread_id IN $s), **$thread_ids**);
```

I tried to grab it this way, but it returns an array in an array and each row is an associative array.  Once I have this data I need to iterate through all the selected rows with something like a while loop.

I did try and do this on my own first, and came up with the below code.  But its not in a usable format.  I need to echo through each item like $row['col_name']; for each column.  The goal is to list all messages that match a thread_id and user_id.

```
$grabThreadList = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT A.* FROM $recipientTableName WHERE A.thread_id IN (SELECT B.thread_id FROM $senderTableName WHERE B.thread_is = A.thread_id "));

    foreach ($grabThreadList as $key => $value){

    $implodeMe = implode(',,,few ', $value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with just SQL if this is what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT thread_id FROM $tableName2 WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM $tableName1 WHERE user_id = %s)
```